# Incorrect code coverage in developer console

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, code-coverage

I have an apex class called RelationshipTreeController (RTC for short) and a test class called RelationshipTreeControllerTest (RTCT for short). I have written a test method that calls the search() method within the RTC class and the test method passes when I run the RTCT in the developer console. However, when I look at the code coverage it only says 55% covered (I have many more methods but only mentioning this one for simplicity). I open up my RTC within the developer console to see the lines covered and it shows the entire search() method in red. Is this a salesforce bug or am I just missing something basic?

Here is my RTCT method to test the search method:

```
 static testMethod void testSearchFunctionality(){
    RelationshipTreeControllerTestUtils.setupForTesting();
    RelationshipTreeControllerTestUtils.createBothWithContactsAndAccountsMixed();

    ApexPages.StandardController stc = new ApexPages.StandardController(RelationshipTreeControllerTestUtils.contactList[0]);
    RelationshipTreeController myExtension = new RelationshipTreeController(stc);

    Assert.assertTrue(myExtension.nameSearch == null);
    Assert.assertTrue(myExtension.searchResults.isEmpty());
    myExtension.nameSearch = 'A';
    myExtension.search();
    Assert.assertTrue(myExtension.errorInSearch);
    myExtension.nameSearch = 'Account';
    myExtension.search();
    Assert.assertTrue(!myExtension.errorInSearch);
    Assert.assertTrue(myExtension.searchResults.size() == 3);
    Assert.assertTrue((myExtension.searchResults[0].childName).equals('Test Account 2'));
    Assert.assertTrue((myExtension.searchResults[1].childName).equals('Test Account 6'));
    Assert.assertTrue((myExtension.searchResults[2].childName).equals('Test Account 7'));
    
    myExtension.clearSearchBar();
    Assert.assertTrue(myExtension.nameSearch == null);
    Assert.assertTrue(myExtension.searchResults.isEmpty());
}
```

And here is a snapshot of my line coverage for RTC
[image]

and my overall code coverage from the Developer Console
[image]

If I am forgetting to mention any pertinent information please let me know.

Comment: Please add your controller class and the Visualforce code.  It looks like your controller extension and the standard one may not be connected, but we won't be able to tell without those.